# Error when trying to update XAP in the windowsphone dev center

Tags: windows-phone-7, xap

I am trying to submit an update for a windows phone app, but when I click "Update app" and I select the appropriate .xap file, the following error message appears:

[ScriptObject_InvokeFailed] Arguments: Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=8.1.10411.0&File=System.Windows.Browser.dll&Key=ScriptObject_InvokeFailed

What is this supposed to mean? This message keeps coming up regardless of the .xap file I select.

Comment: What browser are you using? Please try it with Internet Explorer 9 or above!

Comment: I was using Chrome ver.22 . I tried using Internet Explorer 9 and my problem was solved. Though, I would highly appreciate an answer on why Chrome fails to upload the XAP file.

Comment: Probably just some Javascript or Silverlight compatibility issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Internet Explorer 9 or above, that will probably fix your issue.