# XAP file submission

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error when trying to update XAP in the windowsphone dev center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638950/error-when-trying-to-update-xap-in-the-windowsphone-dev-center)

When I submit my .xap file I'm getting this error.Please look into this.

```
[ScriptObject_InvokeFailed] Arguments: Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often 
the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem.
```

Comment: Are you submitting the release mode xap or debuggin mode xap?  also use the 'Marketplace test kit' in your VS Express to validate your application before submission.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a problem with something going wrong in the browser/javascript

Try IE9 which is the only officially supported browser...

See also [Error when trying to update XAP in the windowsphone dev center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638950/error-when-trying-to-update-xap-in-the-windowsphone-dev-center)